# Cascading null reference exception check?

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

Is there a way to do a generic cascading null reference check in c#?

What i am trying to achieve is if i am trying to access a string variable which is part of a class C, which is inturn in class B, which is in A.

> A.B.C.str

And that i am passed in A, i will have to check to see if A is null, then check if B is null, then check is C is null and then access str.

Is it possible to have some method where -  we can potentially pass in, A and A.B.C.str and it return null is anything was null or value of str if everything existed correctly.

Comment: I smell a Law of Demeter violation.

Comment: I've done something nasty here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657942/nice-way-to-avoid-null-checks-in-ifs

Comment: @rene: That is so wrong in so many ways. I think I like it.

Comment: It would be better to figure out where those nulls are coming from - and stop them near the source.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the compliment :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is no built in way to do this yet, however in C# 6.0 we are expecting a 'safe navigation' operator, see [this post by Jerry Nixon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx)

It will look something like this:

```
var g1 = parent?.child?.child?.child; 
if (g1 != null) // TODO
```

Comment: FTFY ..........  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Exactly what i was hoping for today :) That is awesome .. can't wait for c# 6 then!!!

Comment: Same. The old way of checking each level will still be widely used for obvious reasons but it will definitely clean up some portions of code. In Nixon's post, however, it does not definitively say whether or not this will be in 6.0 or not.

Comment: @VP. according to the `Roslyn` status page, it's ready and will be included: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: You can already do this in .NET 4.0 or at least you can with .NET 4.0 with VS2015

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in possibility in c#, but you can use something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109026/Chained-null-checks-and-the-Maybe-monad

It involves declaring a function thusly:

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
       Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
       where TResult : class where TInput : class
{
  if (o == null) return null;
  return evaluator(o);
}
```

which you can then call like this:

```
string postCode = this.With(x => person)
                      .With(x => x.Address)
                      .With(x => x.PostCode);
```

Comment: FTFY ..........  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers