# Operator for access to member objet same if object is null

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to replace test of null member by operator.

Example :

```
if (myobject !=null and myobject.myprop !=null)
{
    return myobject.myprop.mysubprop;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

It would be the most simple, if by example operator is `==>`:

```
return myobject==>myprop==>mysubprop;   //return null if myobject or myprop is null
```

Comment: Though I am a fan of a "self asked and answered question", this is simply displaying a single feature of C# 6.0. This is demonstrated in numerous existing S.O. posts already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417897/cascading-null-reference-exception-check/24417985#24417985

Answer (score 1):

We can use null-conditional operator `?.` in C# 6 like this:

```
return  myobject?.myprop?.mysubprop;
```